# Retrieve data with promises ( ionic and angular)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, promise

I am trying to retrieve data from my API with promises and work with these values in my functions.... this is my function in the service:

```
getetudiant() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.http.get('http://localhost/eportfolio/etudiantprofile.php')
            .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe(data => {
                resolve(data);
            }, error => {
                reject(error);
            })
    })
}
}
```

and this is my call on my page.ts. The problem is which call the `etudiantstage` outside the function it gives me an empty array.

```
}
getAllStageItems(){
     this.etprofile.getetudiant().then((data: any) => {
        this.etudiantstage = data
        console.log(this.etudiantstage);
    });       

    console.log(this.etudiantstage);

    for(let item in this.etudiantstage){
        console.log(this.etudiantstage[item].cin);
        if(this.etudiantstage[item].cin == this.cin)
        this.validerAffiche = true;}
}
```

This first `console.log(this.etudiantstage)` works but the second doesn't work:

[image: Screen Shot]

Can anyone help me to solve this problem, please !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it is async.

So, if you want to handle data after getting data from servers, the logic should be inside promise/observable subscribe logics.

firstly, make service function to return observable

```
getetudiant() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost/eportfolio/etudiantprofile.php')
            .map(res => res.json())   // should check Http or HttpClient since if you use HttpClient, you do not need to use res=>res.json().
}
```

and

```
getAllStageItems(){
     this.etprofile.getetudiant().subscribe((data: any) => {
        this.etudiantstage = data
        console.log(this.etudiantstage);

    // <= getting data and execute these logic here
    console.log(this.etudiantstage);

    for(let item in this.etudiantstage){
        console.log(this.etudiantstage[item].cin);
        if(this.etudiantstage[item].cin == this.cin)
        this.validerAffiche = true;}
    });       
}
```

Comment: this didn't work because when it try to console.log(this.etudiantstage) after the promise don't show up

Comment: i have tried it but as i seed and it didn't show up the result when i try to console.log(this.etudiantstage) after the promise finish 
this won't work when i want to use the returned value from the promise in other function and

Comment: @mohamedfarjallah could you add full codes? component and service modules.

Comment: sorry thank you this is solve my problem <3 <3 <3 thank you so much